# VScode ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) while Parsing file

Tags: google-app-engine, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I was in the process of uploading a file to Google cloud. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [C:\Users\Samuel\app.yaml]      
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Users\Samuel\app.yaml", line 5, column 7
```

This is the content of the .yaml file

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: _go_app
```

I do not know the issue exactly; it does not run and how do I connect the VS code to my google cloud project? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 2 things in your `app.yaml` file:

1. There is no `runtime: go' entry in known documentation there is only like` g111` up to g114 (for GO 1.14 which currently is in beta) - [reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#example)
2. `api_version` is available and required only for old runtimes ( I found it only in Python2 and PHP5.5) and depreciated in others, for sure not available in Go - [reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements)

I would start with correcting this.

Comment: Thanks, @vitooh, please can you help with the correct form of preparing the file. I am working on a google cloud action project.

Comment: I suggest to use the reference I am referring to... you will find everything there. Have you went trough getting started tutorial?